# Wiring up Backbone.js view and template for dialog box

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In a Backbone.js template, templates/nutrients/show_template.jst.ejs, I have this:

```
<div id="nutrient_container">
<table class="person_nutrients">
...
<% for(var i=0; i < person[nutrientsToRender]().length; i++) { %>
  <% var nutrient = y[x[i]]; %>
  <tr class="deficent_nutrients">
    <td>
    <span class="nutrient_name"><%= I18n.t(nutrient.name) %></span>
    </td>
    <td><a id="show_synonyms" href="#"><%= I18n.t("Synonyms") %></a></td>
<% } %>
</table>
</div>
```

Then, in the Backbone.js view, views/nutrients/show_view.js, I have this:

```
el: 'table.person_nutrients',
parent_el: 'div#nutrient-graphs',
template: JST["backbone/templates/nutrients/show_template"],
initialize: function(options) {
  ...
  this.render()
},
events: {
    'click a#show_synonyms':'synonyms_event'
},
render: function() {
  ...
  $(this.parent_el).append(this.template({person: this.model_object, nutrientsToRender: this.nutrientsToRender(), x: x_prep, y: y_prep}))
}, 
synonyms_event: function(event) {
  alert("I got called");
}
```

Why doesn't the event (the alert box) get triggered? I click the link for "Synonyms" and all I get is the root url with a # after it. Why doesn't the Javascript match up?

Comment: you have to event.preventDefault() before your alert to make sure the link doesn't fire regularly

Comment: @imrane, thanks. Does the wiring up look right, though?

Comment: You need to either set the `el` or `tagName` for the view somewhere

Comment: @Jack, you helped me earlier today, too - thanks. The el and parent_el for the view are set (I didn't show them.) Does the wiring up look right?

Comment: It does, are you changing the view's el somewhere? perhaps you need to call the *re* [delegate](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) your events. You also probably want to call `event.PreventDefault` like @imrane mentioned.

Comment: You mention a *parent_el*, what are you referring to? As far as I know there is no such thing in vanilla Backbone.js, are you using a framework on top of Backbone.js?

Comment: @Jack, I added the el's which are in the view. I don't really understand what the el's do. The site starts with Ruby on Rails and then has Backbone.js after Devise authentication. If you can, please explain more about the delegate suggestion. I don't understand what that does. Thanks very much.

Comment: is table.person_nutrients a parent of a#show_synonyms element? or is it it's sibling?

Comment: @ekeren, this is a very interesting question. I have assumed that table.person_nutrients has rows, and each row includes a a#show_synonyms element. Eventually, I need show_synonyms to be passed a specific "nutrient" referring to which row it is. I haven't yet learned how to pass the information to the alert. Does that help answer your question?

Comment: First of all don't use id='show_synonyms' on multiple elements in a document, id must be unique. use class instead. can you show the entire template file?

Comment: @ekeren, that is very interesting, yes, I made all the links "show_synonyms", and that is likely part of it. I will post the template in a moment. Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: So, @ekeren, I want to pass "nutrient" to the show_synonyms event. You are totally right that show_synonyms should have a different name, since there are going to be N of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the way a view's el works.

In backbone.js views always reference a DOM element which is its `el`, this DOM element can either be an existing element in the page's DOM or it can be a new element that does not exist on the DOM.

The way views in backbone.js *listen* to events is by *delegating* (binding) them to its [el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el). If a view's el changes, or you want to change what events it listens to you can also manually (re)delegate the events by calling the [delegateEvents](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) method

There are two common patterns with views, one is where a view references an existing element on the DOM (this is done by specifying it's el property or passing in an el when it's instantiated), and the second is where the view's el doesn't reference an existing element on the DOM and instead renders some HTML in it's el which is then inserted into the DOM.

Very often what's done is that you have one parent view (often a collections view) which references an existing element on the DOM, and then a bunch of child view's whose el gets appended.

In your case you probably want to split up your view into a parent view that references a higher *container* div, and have the child views' els appended into it.

For example

```
<div id="dvContainer">

<div id="synomCont"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add" />
</div>


var ParentView = Backbone.Views.extend({

   el: 'dvContainer',

   events: {
       "click #add" : "addSyn"
   },

   addSyn: function() {
      //here you can create a model with the approptate data, and pass that in to
      // the view
      var view = new SynomView();
      this.$el.find('#synomCont').append(view.render().el);
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, also to @ekeren. The el was part of the problem. I was able to get the code working after quite a number of changes. I will have a problem remaining, which I will post in a different thread. Thanks so much for helping me.